# Google Places for Business duplicates

Tags: google-my-business

I have added a Google Place for my business but it looks like Google has auto created a place based off a different listing site.

Is there any way I can merge these Google Places so I do not lose a review from either?

Answer (score 1):

From [Google's help page](http://support.google.com/places/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183009&topic=1656742&ctx=topic)

> 1. Make sure you've claimed one of the listings in Google Places. Verify that there’s only one active listing in your account by logging
>      in to your Google Places account.
>
>    1. If there's more than one listing in your account for the same business, you’ll first need to fix that problem by following the steps
>         in the section below.
>    2. If you don't have a listing for it at all, you should claim your business.
> 2. For every extra result for your business, go to its Place Page, click the Report A Problem link, and select "Place has another
>      listing". If you can, include a link to your claimed Place Page in the
>      comments section.
> 3. Google will review these reports and fix duplicate business listings.

Answer (score 0):

If the listings have the same, basic information (name, address, phone number), they likely merge on their own. However, you can elect to use report a problem to have someone look at the listings and merge duplicates. The reviews will eventually all migrate to the final merged page.

If they are different locations, one representing an old store, for example, the old listing should be reported as closed. The reviews, by design, will not migrate.